# how to pass cgrect as parameter and how to get cgrect as a return type in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cgrect

hi all i am going to  ask basic question i searched many links for my question but none of the things not given exact result.here is my question:

I want to pass rect value and returning the same type using some transformation for that i wrote one method but it is giving me the errors i know it may be syntactically wrong please correct the below code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    CGRect testRect=getNewRect(self.view.frame);
}
```

my own method is here

```
CGRect getNewRect(CGRect normalRect){
    //some transformation
    return tranfermedrect;
}
```

give me your suggestion thanks in advance..

Comment: the  message is like this "conflicting types for getNewRect"  if i am changing method name then the error giving me the "conflicting types for latest method name"

Comment: Thanks for yours early replay ...is it write syntactically...

Comment: How does declaration of `getNewRect` method look like?

Comment: Can you show your transformation?

Comment: Have you declared your `CGRect getNewRect(CGRect normalRect)` function in your header file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Used following line you will solve your problem.

```
[self yourFunction:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rectFrame]];
```

Above line is the simple method call and in objective-C you can not send CGRect as a parameter. so you have to CGRect convert into NSValue.

At called function you have get GGRect from NSValue

```
yourView.frame = [rect CGRectValue];
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: ‘in objective-C you can not send CGRect as a parameter’ **That’s not true.** See the `UIView` class reference for examples of methods that accept `CGRect` arguments or methods that return `CGRect` values.

Comment: @Bavarious, ok... sir then show me please how i send CGRect as a parameter through function????????

Comment: As described in the other answers to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Try with below

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    CGRect testRect= [self getNewRect:self.view.frame];
}

-(CGRect) getNewRect:(CGRect) normalRect{

    //some transformation
    return tranfermedrect;
}
```

Add below in .h file

```
  -(CGRect) getNewRect:(CGRect) normalRect ;
```

Comment: Using C functions within an Obj-C class isn't a problem.

Comment: Why shouldn’t he do that? Also, there’s nothing C++-specific in his code.

Comment: @kubi , @Bavarious : you guys are right, i removed that from my answer

Comment: Thanks for your replay i tried this... but if want to print testRect in log giving me error like  "incompatible argument of 1 nsstringFromCGrect"

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    CGRect testRect= [self getNewRect:self.view.frame];
    NSLog(@"New rect %@",NSStringFromCGRect(testRect));
}

-(CGRect) getNewRect:(CGRect) normalRect{

    //some transformation
    return tranformedRect;
}
```

see if this works

Comment: giving me the error some times...i declared testRect as a state not in viewDidLoad